# How to run C++ program from terminal VS Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I want to run a C++ program in VS Code. All I get from Google is that click on run and debug (the play button) on top right in VS Code and my program will be up and running. I don't want to do from that. I want to do it from terminal.

Example, to run:

1. A Python file I do: `python3 fileName.py`
2. A Flutter program: `flutter run`
3. A Java file: `javac fileName.java`
4. A Go file: `go run fileName.go`

Is there any command similar like this in C++?

Apologies, I know my question is a little naïve.

Comment: Call your compiler and run the resulting program, if it was generated?

Comment: the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp) is probably a good place to start

Answer (score 0):

i guess the short answer would be :

> $ g++ -o < name-you-want-to-give> source.cpp

In place of  replace it by any name like myprogram, etc.
./myprogram

This mean you had to install gcc compiler beforehand.

Comment: Hey thankyou for answering. I answered my question. It worked

Answer (score 0):

I need to be in my project directory and then i need to run

```
g++ 01inputFromUser.cpp -o 01inputFromUser && "/home/aman/Desktop/arjun/cpp/"01inputFromUser
```

so this was what I was looking for

```
g++ fileName.cpp -o fileName && "/path/to/project/"fileName
```

Answer (score -1):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hoLG3.png)

i guess the short answer would be :

g++ .\c++\file_name.cpp
./a.exe

Comment: Your answer does not mention how to solve the original problem.